# Trying to serialize data from multiple models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, model, serialization

I am trying to serialize three django models in a section of my api, but it seems he doesn't like the way I do it .. Im following the documentation of https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

I have tried to create 3 serializers one for each model and then put everything together in the fields of the last

serializers.py

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['name', 'user']

class UserCompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserCompany
        fields = ['name']

class UserInfoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = UserProfileSerializer
    companys = UserCompanySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['email', 'profile', 'companys']
```

I thought it would work but it returns the error:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /user_info
>   Field name `profile` is not valid for model `CustomUser`.

models.py

```
class UserCompany(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    companys = models.ForeignKey(UserCompany, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: I think you're missing parenthesis. The line defining `profile` should be `profile = UserProfileSerializer()`.

Comment: now says 'UserCompany' object is not iterable :(

Comment: You should not have `many=True` for the serializer for `companys` since it's not going to be a list.

Comment: thx, but I have two companys assigned to the admin user and it only shows me one `{
        "email": "admin@admin.com",
        "companys": {
            "name": "Default S.L",
            "id": 2
        }
    }`

Comment: According to your model definition, it's not possible for a user to have 2 `companys` since that field is a `ForeignKey`. What you need is for `companys` to be a `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: I want a user to have more than one company, but not that a company can have more than one user, is correct for this pourpose `ManyToManyField?`

Comment: In that case, `UserCompany` should have a `ForeignKey` field to `CustomUser`.